# Straing pair of square brackets "[]" above the list of references

Tags: brackets

Running the following MWE, I get a pair of square brackets "[]" above the list of references. Why? Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{ancientgreek} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text, Numbers=OldStyle} 
\setmainfont{Minion Pro} 
\setmonofont{UM Typewriter} 
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\newpage \cite{*} 
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{/home/roi/Kiel/Deon} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried running your MWE but don't have the fonts nor your bibliography data. Can you please simplify it?

Comment: The effect will be visible even with an empty bib-file. The font doesn't matter too.

Comment: Then it would save us a lot of time if you modified your MWE. Anyway, I think that you should have said `\nocite{*}` instead of `\cite{*}`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\nocite{*}` instead of `\cite{*}`.

Comment: That's it. Thank you so much.